# Как правильно составить SQL-запрос в этом случае?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, веб-программирование

Добрый день,господа.

Необходима Ваша помощь вот в такой ситуации:

**Исходник (дамп + структура):**
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/FAUz/9UkFF1ZFK

**Задача**

Нужно получить факультеты,группы которые относятся к этим факультетам и количество студентов на факультете и в группах.

**Что сделал:**

```js
SELECT facultys.faculty_name,groups.group_name, COUNT(student.id) as num,COUNT(student.id)as group_num
FROM facultys
LEFT OUTER JOIN student ON student.faculty_id = facultys.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups ON student.group_id = groups.id
GROUP BY facultys.faculty_name
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. удалось получить общее количество студентов для факультета и первую группу этого факультета.

Но нужно чтобы запрос вытаскивал все группы факультета и считал количество людей,отдельно для каждой группы.
Пока не понял как это сделать.

**Пример как должно выглядеть:**

Исторический - 2

ФЛ-321 - 1

ФЛ - 234 - 1 (вот эту часть не получил)

Как подправить запрос??

Благодарю за уделенное время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GROUP BY facultys.faculty_name, groups.group_name
```

Comment: Благодарю, Вас. Это сработало.